# Create-react-app version 2 not compatible with SharePoint?

Tags: web-part, react

I'm trying to make a web part with React (not SPFx, just a regular mini React app) for use in SharePoint.

I have done so successfully with version 1.x of `react-scripts`, but now 2.x is out, with enhancements I want to use (SASS, finally), but it seems it's not compatible with SharePoint?  I started with 2.0.3, couldn't get anything to render, and even dumbed down my app to be the following:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

console.log('loaded index.js');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hello World from React.</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Not only is nothing rendered, the `console.log` in index.js is not run, and if I set any breakpoints they are not hit.

I can tell the scripts are getting loaded because if I make any changes to to index.js or App.js, I can see the changes in the source map in the browser's dev tools.

I downgraded `react-scripts` to v.1.1.5, and the app renders and the `console.log` works.  Upgraded to v.2.1.1, doesn't render and the `console.log` doesn't run.

Has anyone run into this issue or know what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this one out.

It wasn't working for me because, as of the change to CRA 2+, [the build process](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/production-build) splits the code into a vendor chunk and your app's code chunk, and most importantly *embeds a small webpack runtime script into the generated `index.html` file*

> which is used to load and run your application.

Since I have been using React "apps" as web parts in SharePoint, I was getting them on to a SharePoint page in one of two ways:

- create a little .`html` file with the root `div` for the app and links to the `.css` and `.js` files in the Site Assets library, then adding a CEWP to the SharePoint page and linking to that `.html` snippet.
- create a visual web part in VisualStudio, and add the root `div` and the links to the `.css` and `.js` files in the web part `.ascx`, usually pointing to somewhere in the `_layouts` folder.

Either way, I was completely *ignoring* the CRA built `index.html`, so I didn't have the webpack runtime script, hence why my little web part apps woudn't run.